# Issues With Printer GPO

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy, user-management, printer, print-server

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 print server. The client machines are Windows 7 Professional. I am having issues with user accounts not getting the printer added when they login.

Things that I have tried:

- Installed Printer Driver In Printer Manager
- Set Printer To Be Shared
- Set the Security Of The Printer To The Correct Group
- Added The User To The Correct Group
- Created A New GPO
- Added The Printer To The GPO (See Image)
- Added The Group To The Security Filtering
- Ran GPUPDATE /Force

[image: GPO Printer]

I have another GPO that I have setup for another printer, and it works fine. The only difference between that GPO and the one that I am having issue with is the security filtering. The filtering on the one that works has the following:

- Everyone
- Domain Users
- Authenticated Users

I have also made a video, so that you can see the steps. Please click [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rXnCyZC7W2Q&feature=youtu.be) to see the video.

Comment: Have you tried changing the action to `Create`, from `Update`?  (I know the documentation says that `Update` is supposed to create the connection if it doesn't exist, but my experience has been that this doesn't always work.)

Comment: Has the user logged out and back in so that his/her token contains the security group membership?

Comment: @HopelessN00b The other GPO uses Update as well, and it works fine.

Comment: @joeqwerty Yes I have logged in and out a hand full of times

Comment: I looked into this method a couple years ago in our initial 7 roll out. Even got it fully implemented. It was always hit or miss even after a lot of hours debugging the processing. In the end I opted for a login script that read the group memberships I was using for item level targeting. 

Good luck.

Comment: Are the clients Windows 7 or XP? Does that same client work with the other GPO? If it's XP http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3628

Comment: @Nixphoe I updated the question. They are Widnows 7 Pro clients

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the GPO you need to check the box "Run in logged-in user's security context"

Answer (score 2):

One one of the computers where the printers are not installed, run the following:

```
gpresult /h gpresult.html
```

From the user's logon context.

This will show the user's group memberships, and the GPO's applied/denied.  This will help you narrow down if it is an issue with group membership not being picked up, or if the GPO's aren't being processed, or if the computer does not even report on the GPO.

Comment: Where is the .html file save @?

Comment: @nate in the same directory that you ran the command from, ie c:\users\username\> gpresult /h > gpresult.html
Would put the file in c:\users\username\gpresult.html

Comment: It says it is inaccessible, on the one the that I am having issues with, and the on that works says empty. I am going to attach the html file to my question

Comment: @nate: Give Authenticated Users Read permission on the GPO, but uncheck the box for Apply Group Policy.

Comment: @nate: Sounds like they aren't pickup up the group membership.